# Unit ( Metric) Problem : Not able to get full 20cm

Tags: faces, units, extrude

im looking for days now ...

I changed my Scene to be Metric, with Degrees and Scale to 0.001.

Objekt Display / Lines: 50 / Scale: 0.01

I need an Icosahedron with 20cm long Edges.
I get 20.019cm or 19.978cm etc and its not like i didnt try to type it in...but i guess, when I type it, Blender will use its own Units and force them into metric messurements.

I want to  have an Scale/Unit system that works on 20.xcm max characters but exactly.

Either having an easy manual scale or to have a perfect "type it in" choice would be greate.

Question aside from that, i didnt find anything regarding ( maybe because i dont know how its called) but i want to work on an objekt lets say a cube, and i want to extrude every face of it and scale it, but i want the faces to have all the same values/ same modification as different faces: im asking because when selecting all the faces and extruding it acts weird or it will just be dublicated.

x3 tanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly here we go:

### First issue.

Blender doesn't have so precise modeling system as CAD software. So if you want correct edge lenght you will need to do this manually.

While scaling object in *Edit Mode* with selected edge lenght you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get more precision. Zooming in and holding cursor (before hitting <kbd>S</kbd>) away from object center could help a bit.

[image: Sphere]

### Second.

In *Edit Mode* change *Pivot Center* to *Individual Origins* then in tools choose *Extrude Individual*, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> to scale down each face.

[image: Cube]

Comment: Thanks LukeD, that helped me alot :), but i guess using blender for exact measurements its kind of a pain. And that "Pivot Center" was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: If you search trough the web for 'Blender CAD addon' there are some but for older Blender versions. I've never used them so I can't tell if they can help you also if my answer was good enough, consider accepting it or/and upvoting.